# Saxon genitive usage

Tags: possessives

Could someone please let me know which is more correct? Or are they both correct maybe?

> - The Company's board of directors has decided....
> - The board of directors of the company has decided...

Comment: Thanks very much. Capitalization of "company" was unintentional.

Comment: Why is the title of this "Saxon genitive usage?"

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

> The Company's Board of Directors has decided

Since you are expressing "belonging". The Board of Directors is a component of a larger entity (the company) and so is best expressed with possessive **'s**. That said, there's nothing wrong with the other option, I just think that using **'s** works more nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid, the first is probably more common.

A better summary than I can give about when to use which form can be found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of).

Comment: Please expand this answer. Maybe you could include some reasons _why_ the first option is preferred, like avoiding the duplication of "of".